# DFS puzzle game solver (java)

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I'm working with DFS solver on 8 puzzle game. This code print all children from the tree until the correct state, but I want to print only the correct solution.

My output:

```
120
345
678

125
340
678

102
345
678

125
348
670

125
304
678

142
305
678

012
345
678
```

Expected output:

```
120 
345
678

102 
345 
678

012 
345 
678
```

Code:

```
public class puzzle {

    public static LinkedHashSet<String> OPEN = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    public static HashSet<String> CLOSED = new HashSet<String>();
    public static boolean STATE = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int statesVisited = 0;

        String start = "120345678";
        String goal = "012345678";
        String X = "";
        String temp = "";

        OPEN.add(start);

        while (OPEN.isEmpty() == false && STATE == false) {
            X = OPEN.iterator().next();
            OPEN.remove(X);
            print(X);

            int pos = X.indexOf('0'); // get position of ZERO or EMPTY SPACE
            if (X.equals(goal)) {
                System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                STATE = true;
            } else {
                // generate children
                CLOSED.add(X);

                temp = up(X, pos);
                if (!(temp.equals("-1")))
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                temp = down(X, pos);
                if (!(temp.equals("-1")))
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    temp = left(X, pos);
                if (!(temp.equals("-1")))
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                temp = right(X, pos);
                if (!(temp.equals("-1")))
                    OPEN.add(temp);
            }

        }
    }
    /*
     * MOVEMENT UP
     */
    public static String up(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (!(p < 3)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p - 3)) + '0' + newS.substring(p - 2);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT DOWN
     */
    public static String down(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (!(p > 5)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p + 3)) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 4);
        }

        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT LEFT
     */
    public static String left(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 7) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p - 1)) + '0' + newS.substring(p);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT RIGHT
     */
    public static String right(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (p != 2 && p != 5 && p != 8) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p + 1)) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 2);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
        System.out.println(s.substring(3, 6));
        System.out.println(s.substring(6, 9));
        System.out.println();


    }
}
```

Comment: I want to print only the correct solution. Right now, my code returns all childs and I want to return only the correct way and not all possible moves.

Comment: Why are you using this data model?

Comment: @RoyShahaf what other model would you propose ?

Comment: I would recommend describing a 2d board of cells in a 2d array

Comment: @RoyShahaf Yes. I thought so. It is a valid and common solution. The 2D array is easier to manage and manipulate and program, but one string model has slight performance advantage.

Comment: @c0der

That isn't precisely true, copying a 2d array is as fast as copying a longer 1d char array (aka string) but the swap operation with a 2d array doesn't create tons of extra memory, where as the excessive use of substring and concat does.
Also note that using "indexOf" (while quite fast) is definitely slower than the approach I use (although I admit I can add the "zeroPosition" into Node and spare myself the "indexOf")

Comment: By the way, here is an error in your implementation of **left** method. Currently condition in **if** statement is `p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 7` but should be `p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 6`

Comment: @RoyShahaf "That isn't precisely true" :  the performance advantage that I wrote about is based on implementing two such models and measuring. The advantage of string model was small, but consistent. As far as I could tell it is mainly due to the costly comparison of 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS returns the first path it finds. To get the shortest path use BFS.
You can use a map

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> paths = new HashMap<>();
```

to map each node (state) to the path that led to it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class puzzle {

    private static LinkedHashSet<String> OPEN = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private static HashSet<String> CLOSED = new HashSet<>();
    private static Map<String, List<String>> paths = new HashMap<>();
    public static boolean STATE = false;


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String start = "120345678";
        String goal =  "012345678";
        String X = "";
        String temp = "";
        OPEN.add(start);
        paths.put(start, Arrays.asList(start));

        while (OPEN.isEmpty() == false && STATE == false) {
            X = OPEN.iterator().next();
            OPEN.remove(X);
            print(X);


            int pos = X.indexOf('0'); // get position of ZERO or EMPTY SPACE
            if (X.equals(goal)) {
                System.out.println("SUCCESS" +"\n" + paths.get(X));
                STATE = true;
            } else {
                // generate children
                CLOSED.add(X);

                temp = up(X, pos);
                if (!temp.equals("-1")) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    updatePaths(temp, paths.get(X));
                }
                temp = down(X, pos);
                if (!temp.equals("-1")) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    updatePaths(temp, paths.get(X));
                }
                    temp = left(X, pos);
                if (!temp.equals("-1")) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    updatePaths(temp, paths.get(X));
                }
                temp = right(X, pos);
                if (!temp.equals("-1")) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    updatePaths(temp, paths.get(X));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void updatePaths(String s, List<String> path){

        if(paths.containsKey(s)) return;
        List<String> newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
        newPath.add(s);
        paths.put(s, newPath);
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT UP
     */
    public static String up(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (!(p < 3)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, p - 3) + '0' + newS.substring(p - 2);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT DOWN
     */
    public static String down(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (!(p > 5)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, p + 3) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 4);
        }

        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT LEFT
     */
    public static String left(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 7) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, p - 1) + '0' + newS.substring(p);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT RIGHT
     */
    public static String right(String s, int p) {
        String str = s;
        if (p != 2 && p != 5 && p != 8) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, p + 1) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 2);
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return "-1";
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
       System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
       System.out.println(s.substring(3, 6));
       System.out.println(s.substring(6, 9));
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Online code can be reviewed and executed [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/sRydLbLNbM)  and a refactored version [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2YLxF5Y2To)

Comment: your code still prints all possible children, but I need only the correct solution...

Comment: I don't think it does. The output contains the 7 steps needed to find a solution.

Comment: Yes you are true, but I need the shortest solution to win that game.
In my case, the shortest solution will be: 120 345 678 -> 
102 345 678 ->

012 345 678. I don't need to print all possible combinations, only the shortest solution.

Comment: That would be a breadth first search; based on your question, you're asking about a depth first search, which just gives the first path it finds.

Comment: I apologise c0der, but I still need with the DFS, with the first path it finds, but only with the correct one, not all children.

Comment: @l1den whether you use dfs or bfs you can return the first path you find.
The difference is that bfs also guarantees that the solution returned is the shortest path

Comment: I understand Roy and thank you again for your time, but I need to use DFS. @RoyShahaf

Comment: sure, my code has comments with the code changes needed to turn my solution into DFS

Answer (score 1):

We need somehow save relation between steps to find only steps from successful path.

Here is my solution:

```
public class Puzzle {

    public static LinkedHashSet<Step> open = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    public static HashSet<Step> closed = new HashSet<>();
    public static boolean problemSolved = false;

    private static class Step {

        final String data;

        Step previous = null;

        Step(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        Step(Step previous, String data) {
            this.previous = previous;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public Step getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder()
                    .append(data.substring(0, 3))
                    .append("\r\n")
                    .append(data.substring(3, 6))
                    .append("\r\n")
                    .append(data.substring(6, 9))
                    .toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Step)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }
            return this.getData().equals(((Step) obj).getData());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.getData().hashCode();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int statesVisited = 0;

        Step startStep = new Step("120345678");
        Step goalStep = new Step("012345678");
        Step currentStep;

        open.add(startStep);

        while (!open.isEmpty() && !problemSolved) {
            currentStep = open.iterator().next();
            open.remove(currentStep);
            // print(currentStep);

            if (currentStep.equals(goalStep)) {
                System.out.println("SUCCESS PATH: \r\n");
                printSuccessPath(
                        getSuccessPathFromFinishStep(currentStep) // here currentStep is finish step
                );
                problemSolved = true;
            } else {
                // generate children
                closed.add(currentStep);

                Step nextStep = up(currentStep);
                if (nextStep != null) {
                    open.add(nextStep);
                }

                nextStep = down(currentStep);
                if (nextStep != null) {
                    open.add(nextStep);
                }

                nextStep = left(currentStep);
                if (nextStep != null) {
                    open.add(nextStep);
                }

                nextStep = right(currentStep);
                if (nextStep != null) {
                    open.add(nextStep);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT UP
     */
    public static Step up(Step step) {
        int p = step.getData().indexOf('0');
        String str = step.getData();
        if (!(p < 3)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p - 3)) + '0' + newS.substring(p - 2);
        }
        Step nexStep = new Step(step, str); // Creates new step with step as previous one
        // Eliminates child of X if its on open or closed
        if (!open.contains(nexStep) && !closed.contains(nexStep))
            return nexStep;
        else
            return null;
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT DOWN
     */
    public static Step down(Step step) {
        int p = step.getData().indexOf('0');
        String str = step.getData();
        if (!(p > 5)) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 3);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p + 3)) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 4);
        }
        Step nexStep = new Step(step, str); // Creates new step with step as previous one
        // Eliminates child of X if its on open or closed
        if (!open.contains(nexStep) && !closed.contains(nexStep))
            return nexStep;
        else
            return null;
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT LEFT
     */
    public static Step left(Step step) {
        int p = step.getData().indexOf('0');
        String str = step.getData();
        if (p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 7) {
            char a = str.charAt(p - 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p - 1)) + '0' + newS.substring(p);
        }
        Step nexStep = new Step(step, str); // Creates new step with step as previous one
        // Eliminates child of X if its on open or closed
        if (!open.contains(nexStep) && !closed.contains(nexStep))
            return nexStep;
        else
            return null;
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT RIGHT
     */
    public static Step right(Step step) {
        int p = step.getData().indexOf('0');
        String str = step.getData();
        if (p != 2 && p != 5 && p != 8) {
            char a = str.charAt(p + 1);
            String newS = str.substring(0, p) + a + str.substring(p + 1);
            str = newS.substring(0, (p + 1)) + '0' + newS.substring(p + 2);
        }
        Step nexStep = new Step(step, str); // Creates new step with step as previous one
        // Eliminates child of X if its on open or closed
        if (!open.contains(nexStep) && !closed.contains(nexStep))
            return nexStep;
        else
            return null;
    }

    private static void print(Step s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printSuccessPath(List<Step> successPath) {
        for (Step step : successPath) {
            print(step);
        }
    }

    private static List<Step> getSuccessPathFromFinishStep(Step finishStep) {
        LinkedList<Step> successPath = new LinkedList<>();

        Step step = finishStep;
        while (step != null) {
            successPath.addFirst(step);
            step = step.getPrevious();
        }

        return successPath;
    }
}
```

I've refactored your code a bit. And introduced new class **Step** which allows us to save relation between current step and previous one.

Logic is a bit complicated, but feel free to ask additional question if something if not clear for you)

And, by the way, here is the result:

```
SUCCESS PATH: 

120
345
678

102
345
678

012
345
678
```

Comment: Thank you brother!

Comment: This is DFS or BFS?

Comment: @l1den It’s BFS.

Answer (score 1):

So, a clean(er) solution that does what you've asked for looks like this:

```
package basic;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Puzzle {

    private static class Node {
        private final Node previous;
        private final String data;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((data == null) ? 0 : data.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        public Node getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Node other = (Node) obj;
            if (data == null) {
                if (other.data != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public Node(String data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = null;
        }

        public Node(String data, Node previous) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue<Node> open = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<Node> closed = new HashSet<>();
        Node start = new Node("120345678");
        Node goal = new Node("012345678");

        open.add(start);
        boolean solving = true;
        while (!open.isEmpty() && solving) {
            Node current = open.poll();
            int pos = current.getData().indexOf('0');
            if (!closed.contains(current)) {
                if (current.equals(goal)) {
                    printPath(current);
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                    solving = false;
                } else {
                    // generate children
                    up(current, pos, open, closed);
                    down(current, pos, open, closed);
                    left(current, pos, open, closed);
                    right(current, pos, open, closed);
                    closed.add(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT UP
     */
    private static void up(Node current, int zeroPosition, Queue<Node> open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (zeroPosition >= 3) {
            char substitutedChar = current.getData().charAt(zeroPosition - 3);
            open.add(new Node(current.getData().substring(0, zeroPosition - 3) + '0'
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition - 2, zeroPosition) + substitutedChar
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition + 1), current));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT DOWN
     */
    private static void down(Node current, int zeroPosition, Queue<Node> open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (zeroPosition <= 5) {
            char substitutedChar = current.getData().charAt(zeroPosition + 3);
            open.add(new Node(current.getData().substring(0, zeroPosition) + substitutedChar
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition + 1, zeroPosition + 3) + '0'
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition + 4), current));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT LEFT
     */
    private static void left(Node current, int zeroPosition, Queue<Node> open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (zeroPosition % 3 != 0) {
            char substitutedChar = current.getData().charAt(zeroPosition - 1);
            open.add(new Node(current.getData().substring(0, zeroPosition - 1) + '0' + substitutedChar
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition + 1), current));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT RIGHT
     */
    private static void right(Node current, int zeroPosition, Queue<Node> open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (zeroPosition % 3 != 2) {
            char substitutedChar = current.getData().charAt(zeroPosition - 1);
            open.add(new Node(current.getData().substring(0, zeroPosition) + substitutedChar + '0'
                    + current.getData().substring(zeroPosition + 2), current));
        }
    }

    private static void printPath(Node current) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (; current != null; current = current.getPrevious()) {
            stack.push(current.getData());
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            print(stack.pop());
        }
    }

    private static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
        System.out.println(s.substring(3, 6));
        System.out.println(s.substring(6, 9));
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Do note that I haven't changed the basic board representation (you chose to use String, while I recommend using a 2d array, where swaps are much less costly and the code becomes easier to understand)

A few notes:

1. To print the entire "path" you must maintain connections between the "steps" of your solution
2. Avoid using globals where possible
3. Prefer using Interfaces (Set, Queue) as the types of your collections (and choose them based on how you would use them)
4. Java 8 doesn't require you to specify the concrete types used in a generic collection during construction (So use `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();` instead of using `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();`
5. Where possible, avoid using superfluous (and less readable) conditions / code structure (prefer `if (booleanVariable)` over `if (booleanVariable == true)`

(There are probably a few more things to take away from this, but this is a useful list to start with)

EDIT:
a version where data is a 2d array is added below
    package basic;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Puzzle {

    private static class Node {
        private final Node previous;
        private final char[][] data;

        public Node getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public char[][] getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public int getZeroX() {
            return zeroX;
        }

        public int getZeroY() {
            return zeroY;
        }

        private final int zeroX;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(data);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Node other = (Node) obj;
            if (!Arrays.deepEquals(data, other.data))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private final int zeroY;

        public Node(Node previous, char[][] data, int zeroX, int zeroY) {
            super();
            this.previous = previous;
            this.data = data;
            this.zeroX = zeroX;
            this.zeroY = zeroY;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue<Node> open = new LinkedList<>(); //Stack<Node> open = new Stack<>();
        Set<Node> closed = new HashSet<>();
        Node start = new Node(null, new char[][] { { '1', '2', '0' }, { '3', '4', '5' }, { '6', '7', '8' } }, 2, 0);
        Node goal = new Node(null, new char[][] { { '0', '1', '2' }, { '3', '4', '5' }, { '6', '7', '8' } }, 0, 0);

        open.add(start); //open.push(start);
        boolean solving = true;
        while (!open.isEmpty() && solving) {
            Node current = open.poll(); //open.pop();
            if (!closed.contains(current)) {
                if (current.equals(goal)) {
                    printPath(current);
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                    solving = false;
                } else {
                    // generate children
                    up(current, open, closed);
                    down(current, open, closed);
                    left(current, open, closed);
                    right(current, open, closed);
                    closed.add(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT UP
     */
    private static void up(Node current, Queue<Node>/*Stack<Node>*/ open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (current.getZeroY() > 0) {
            char[][] chars = copy(current.getData());
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX()] = chars[current.getZeroY() - 1][current.getZeroX()];
            chars[current.getZeroY() - 1][current.getZeroX()] = '0';
            open.add/*push*/(new Node(current, chars, current.getZeroX(), current.getZeroY() - 1));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT DOWN
     */
    private static void down(Node current, Queue<Node>/*Stack<Node>*/ open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (current.getZeroY() < 2) {
            char[][] chars = copy(current.getData());
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX()] = chars[current.getZeroY() + 1][current.getZeroX()];
            chars[current.getZeroY() + 1][current.getZeroX()] = '0';
            open.add/*push*/(new Node(current, chars, current.getZeroX(), current.getZeroY() + 1));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT LEFT
     */
    private static void left(Node current, Queue<Node>/*Stack<Node>*/ open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (current.getZeroX() > 0) {
            char[][] chars = copy(current.getData());
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX()] = chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX() - 1];
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX() - 1] = '0';
            open.add/*push*/(new Node(current, chars, current.getZeroX() - 1, current.getZeroY()));
        }
    }

    /*
     * MOVEMENT RIGHT
     */
    private static void right(Node current, Queue<Node>/*Stack<Node>*/ open, Set<Node> closed) {
        if (current.getZeroX() < 2) {
            char[][] chars = copy(current.getData());
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX()] = chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX() + 1];
            chars[current.getZeroY()][current.getZeroX() + 1] = '0';
            open.add/*push*/(new Node(current, chars, current.getZeroX() + 1, current.getZeroY()));
        }
    }

    private static char[][] copy(char[][] data) {
        char[][] newData = new char[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                newData[i][j] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
        return newData;
    }

    private static void printPath(Node current) {
        Stack<char[][]> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (; current != null; current = current.getPrevious()) {
            stack.push(current.getData());
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            print(stack.pop());
        }
    }

    private static void print(char[][] chars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(chars[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

EDIT2: added comments of changes that turn this into DFS

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, Roy, that's perfect! Can you show me another version please with 2d array? You are the best! Thank you!

Comment: added to my answer

Comment: Also, note that in the implementation that I've attached (and the solutions others have attached, including your own attempt) we are doing BFS, not DFS (we are adding the neighbours of our starting position, then adding their neighbours, and so on). To use DFS I would swap my Queue for a Stack (basically it means neighbours of neighbour will be treated before other neighbours of current)

Comment: Oh, really? :( And can you help me with the DFS algorithm also? I'm little stuck right now...

Comment: added comments that turn this into DFS

Comment: Something is weird when I try to change that Node (start state) I don't have any output, it works only with { '1', '2', '0' }, { '3', '4', '5' }, { '6', '7', '8' } }. And also, what is that zeroX = 2?

Comment: you must change zeroX and zeroY appropriately, they describe the position of zero in the node (so the starting position is x=2, y=0, and final position should be x=0, y=0)

Comment: and if my start state is 123045678 x will be 3 and y will be 0?

Comment: No, for {{ '1', '2', '3' }, { '0', '4', '5' }, { '6', '7', '8' } }, x=0 and y=1